# Proper maps in terms of projection from pullback

Tags: general-topology, continuity, category-theory, compactness

I've read that a *continuous* $f:X\rightarrow S$ is proper (inverse images of compacts are compacts) iff for all other continuous maps $g:Y\rightarrow S$ the projection $X\times _SY\rightarrow Y$ in the pullback square below (in $\mathsf{Top}$) is a closed map.
$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
    X\times _S Y @>>> Y\\ @VVV @VV{g}V\\
    X @>>{f}> S
    \end{CD}$$

1. How does one prove this?
2. Does it fail if we drop the assmptions
   $f,g$ are continuous? I.e we let the pullback be in $\mathsf{Set}$,
   with the pullback still topologized as a subspace of the product.

Comment: This is in Top? What's your definition of "proper" (inverse image of compact is compact, or something else)? What's the definition of the subscripted product?

Comment: What's your definition of proper map if not this?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, Zhen, I editted the question to clarify

Comment: (1) The proof is not obvious even in the special case where $S$ is a point. It involves some carefully chosen topological spaces. See [tag `005M`](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/005M) in [Stacks].

Comment: Maps with this property are called *universally closed*. It turns out that universally closed maps are precisely the *perfect maps* (closed maps with compact fibers, sometimes called *proper maps*), as proven in the page linked by Zhen Lin.